# Trigger AWS lambda for specific Kinesis event push

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, apache-camel-aws-kinesis

I am new in AWS lambda area. I am creation a function which will consume Kinesis events. But I want to trigger my lambda function when specific event get push to kinesis (not for all events push to Kinesis). Is there a way that I can configure a filter upfront or my function needs to implement that filter after consuming all events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is to split out the event you are interested on a separate stream either by:

- Use Amazon Kinesis Analytics to copy records to an "event of interest" stream
- Trigger another AWS Lambda function to copy records to an "event of interest" stream

Both of these in front of the lambda you currently have, and then connect that lambda to the new stream.